# loading a markup if a class exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want load a markup into my documents based on the present of some classes in the document.But the problem is if the definite class does not exists at all it loads.

### My codes are

```
(function($){
   'use strict';
    var prefixMarkUp = '<ul class="filter-elements hidden" >'+
                          '<li><a href="#" class="current"></a></li>'+
                        '</ul>';

    if($('body').has('.filter-container')){
      if(!$('body').hasClass('filter-elements')){
        $('footer.footer').before(prefixMarkUp)
      }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Here if `.filter-container` does not exists `prefixmarkup` loads and even if `.filter-elements` exists `prefixmarkup` loads
What should i do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**

- The `.hasClass()` method will return true if the class is assigned to an element, even if other classes also are.
- The `.has()` method constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the matching elements.

**Your need to change:**

```
if($('body').has('.filter-container')){
```

**To:**

```
if($('body').has('.filter-container').length){
```

**FIDDLE (example):** https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/c8nwp813/1/

Learn more [here](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) and [here](https://api.jquery.com/has/).

Answer (score 0):

adding `length` to any jQuery object will return the number of elements selected. So you could do the following.

```
if( $('.filter-container').length ){
    if( !$('body').hasClass('filter-elements') ){
        $('body').before(prefixMarkUp)
    }
}
```

if `$('.filter-container').length` is greater than 0 the statement will be true and the second if statement will be checked. If it is 0, the statement will be false.

You could also use `length` for the second if statement like this. But `!$('body').hasClass('filter-elements')` is more readable.

```
if( !$('body.filter-elements').length ){
    $('body').before(prefixMarkUp)
}
```